# An object was hit by a beam - unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting, gameobject, qvector3d

I have this code for a laser, I want to load a new scene when the laser is touching the player.
this script does not work, I'll happy for your help! :)

```
 void Update()
    {
        Vector3 Point = transform.position + transform.forward * Dis;

        if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, Dis))
        {
            if (hit.collider.tag == "Player")
                SceneManager.LoadScene(2);

            GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(0, transform.position);
            GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(1, hit.point);
            luzColosao.transform.position = hit.point - pos;
        }
        else
        {
            GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(0, transform.position);
            GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(1, Point);
            luzColosao.transform.position = Point;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that everything's ok in your code. use `Debug.Draw` to check your Raycast direction. This function will draw a line exactly the same path that your Raycast will go in your editor. if this Line was correctly hit to player, so you have to check your conditions. Read unity's manual [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html)

```
void Update()
    {

        Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * Dist;

        Vector3 Point = transform.position + transform.forward * Dis;

        if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, Dis))
        {
            if (hit.collider.tag == "Player")
                SceneManager.LoadScene(2);

            GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(0, transform.position);
            GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(1, hit.point);
            luzColosao.transform.position = hit.point - pos;

            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward, Color.green);
        }
        else
        {
            GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(0, transform.position);
            GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(1, Point);
            luzColosao.transform.position = Point;

            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward, Color.red);
        }
    }
```